# Network Error when pushing CiviCRM button

Tags: wordpress

I’m having the same issue as what appears to be listed here:

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17864

I get the same "Network Error" message every time I press the CiviCRM button on the WordPress 'new page' screen when using Chome, FF, and Safari. Perhaps it is an admin or setup error on my part, and not a CiviCRM issue.

I took a screen shot that includes the browser console log if it might be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the screen shot would be helpful to begin isolating the issue.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2mwt508/9

Answer (score 2):

Your page edit screen shows (I think) a URL of the form 'http://domain.ca/civicrm/wp-admin...' whilst the 404 error is looking for 'http://domain.ca/wp-admin/admin.php'. This suggests to me that you're using WordPress Multisite with CiviCRM active on a site that is not the main site. This is not supported at present - CiviCRM is only functional on the main site of a multisite instance.

Edit: this URL schema could also be the result of installing CiviCRM in a sub-directory. This is also unsupported, though [it's an issue that's being addressed](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/WordPress+installed+in+its+own+directory+issues).

Comment: I have a client who uses CiviCRM multisite very actively in a WordPress multisite (subdirectory-based, not subdomain).  It's been going for over a year successfully with minimal pain, and posted basic docs to the multisite wiki page.  I'm wondering what's unsupported?

Comment: I'd be interested to know how they're doing this, Jon. Network-activating CiviCRM in WP multisite (sub-dirs) leads to all CiviCRM back-end URLs pointing to the CiviCRM back-end on the main site. Can you post an URL to the wiki page you're referring to?

Comment: I created a separate question for this, since we're getting off-topic (here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9602/how-can-you-set-up-civicrm-multisite-with-wordpress-multisite/9603#9603).  In short though - you put a "switch" statement into civicrm.settings.php, and define your BASE_URL in the switch statement.

Comment: The answer provided fixed the problem. I started from scratch with a clean install and was sure not to click the 'multisite' checkbox.  Thank-you.